# SharedPreference, facebook integration, NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying facebook integration with my app.
I have my login button inside a fragment which is inside an activity.

when I go back to my main activity and come back to my facebook activity. 
I get null pointer exception.
I am using Shared preference to keep the data of the user and set it on the specific textViews.

**Fragment with facebook login(I removed the imports for the sake of question)**

```
public class Profilee extends Fragment {
    static String email1, birthday1, gender1;
    ImageView imageView;
    static int itis = 1;
    TextView texty;
    LoginButton button;
    LinearLayout userinput;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    private TextView email, birthday, gende;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    static String mail,gender,name;


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            GraphRequest graphrequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                try {
                                    email1 = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                    gender1 = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                    birthday1 = jsonObject.getString("birthday");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email, gender, birthday");
            graphrequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphrequest.executeAsync();
            AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };

    public Profilee() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public boolean m;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hello", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            pref.getString("name", "asdfgh");
            pref.getString("email", "qwerty");
            pref.getString("gender", "zxcvb");



            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
                }
            };



        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            }
        };

        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilee, container, false);
        button = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        TextView button12 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PrifileEdit.class);
                i.putExtra("st", email1);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        texty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emo);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.asd);
        userinput = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.userdetail);
        int unicode = 0x1F60E;
        String emoji = getEmijoByUnicode(unicode);
        String text = "We will never post on your wall without permission ";
        texty.setText(text + emoji);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return v;
    }


    public String getEmijoByUnicode(int unicode) {
        return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        gende = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        birthday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.birth);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ViewCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onResume();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    public void displayMessage(final Profile profile) {

        pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hello", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        m=pref.getBoolean("key",true);


            if(m==true) {
                if (profile != null) {
                    textView.setText(profile.getName());
                    email.setText(email1);
                    gende.setText(gender1);
                    birthday.setText(birthday1);
                    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    texty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    userinput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("hello", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);


                    editor.putString("email",email1);
                    editor.putString("name",profile.getName());
                    editor.putString("gender",gender1);
                    editor.putBoolean("key",false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } else if(m==false){
                mail=pref.getString("email","lol1");
                gender=pref.getString("gender","lol2");
                name=pref.getString("name","lol3");
                textView.setText(name);
                email.setText(mail);
                gende.setText(gender);


            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
    }
}
```

**Acitivty with the above fragment**

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    TextView textView, textView2;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    private static String totalurl = "random.com/l.php";
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "User" ;
    public static final String UserID = "UserIDKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redeem);

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        totalearn();
        textView.setText("₹ " + sp.getString("A_EARN", ""));
        textView2.setText("₹ "+sp.getString("T_EARN",""));

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Profilee(), "PROFILE");
        adapter.addFragment(new Redeem(), "REDEEM");
        //adapter.addFragment(new History(), "HISTORY");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }


        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
    public void redeem(View v){
        Intent internet = new Intent();
        internet.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        internet.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        internet.setData("my"));
        startActivity(internet);
    }
}
```

**LogCAT**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: earn.free.cashback.snapcash, PID: 3959
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.fragments.Profilee.displayMessage(Profilee.java:241)
at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.fragments.Profilee.onResume(Profilee.java:268)
at earn.free.cashback.snapcash.fragments.Profilee.onCreate(Profilee.java:149)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1951)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:926)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:876)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1175)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: post the stacktrace completely

Comment: Appears the TextView reference is null or the value you are passing is a null

Comment: yeah its null but why, am trying to save the values in sharedPreferences's variable ...

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa - am uploading the complete logcat.. just a sec

Comment: my situation is , when I login to facebook the first time, I am able to fetch all the details of the user and able to set them on various textviews.. but once  I go back my main activity and then from main activity to login activity again, it crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Before setting setText make sure that you are not passing NULL value. I think the problem lies here, the values passed must be null, hence NullPointerException.

```
                email.setText(email1);
                gende.setText(gender1);
                birthday.setText(birthday1);
```

Comment: I know its passing null value, but I wanna know how I should I go with the implementation of sharedpreference so that I don't put null values in them .

Comment: before passing value check if it contains NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onResume()` to look like this:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        email = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        gende = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gender);
        birthday = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.birth);
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getContext());
    }
```

Comment: yeah i have :) but some other way